# Cent OS 7 libpng16.so.16 can't open shared object file

Tags: linux, bash, centos, rpm, shared-library

I am attempting to use a program XPDFReader on CentOS 7 it keeps throwing the error `error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I have tried installing this and i used grep to check and it was definitely installed on the correct usr/ path and i used the sudo ldconfig command and reset my pc after and still i get this error.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run `ldconfig -p | grep libpng`. Do you see the library listed in the output?

Comment: With that command no only 15.15 shows up but with sudo find / -name libpng16.so.16 it does show up. Did i miss a step?

Comment: From this [link](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=66774), it seems like there is no clean way to do what you are trying to do unfortunately. That is to say, it seems as though libpng16 is not meant to be on centos 7. I'm not sure if there are different versions of XPDFReader that exist that could use libpng15.

Comment: When you say no clean way does that mean there is a way?

Comment: I was just reiterating what I read from the link I provided, there may be a way to do it, but it sounds like that is not advised.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 doesn't include this library.

It contains:

```
libpng-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        19 Oct 13 15:52 /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15 -> libpng15.so.15.13.0
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root    179328 Oct 13 15:52 /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15.13.0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         0 Oct 13 15:52 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root    192660 Sep 27  2012 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13/CHANGES
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      4205 Sep 27  2012 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13/LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root     10418 Sep 27  2012 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13/README
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      1120 Aug 27  2010 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13/TODO
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root     31690 Sep 27  2012 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13/example.c
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root    195566 Sep 27  2012 /usr/share/doc/libpng-1.5.13/libpng-manual.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      1146 Oct 13 15:52 /usr/share/man/man5/png.5.gz
```

XPDFReader doesn't look like an application included in the official RHEL/CentOS repos. I'm not sure it will work in CentOS even if you install this libpng version which you absolutely can do.

The official Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox releases both work in CentOS and can open PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

libpng16 is [available](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/libpng16.html) as a package from the commercial GetPageSpeed repository, so there's a clean (but not a free) way to install it:

```bsh
sudo yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
sudo yum -y install libpng16
```

Comment: Requires a subscription.